# Need some advise with coding Opacity in my background

Tags: css, opacity

I have this code

```
<h2 style="background-color: #c0c0c0; padding: 1em; max-width: 15em; opacity: 0.2; ;margin: 1em 10px; text-align: right;"><strong>HANDMADE TIES
</strong>DISCOVER NOW</h2>
&nbsp;
```

But I cannot figure out how to make the background opacity only, while text remains of its own color. Also I would like the text Handmade ties to be H2 while Discover now to be a paragraph.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Daniel Murphy the code is in my post

Answer (score 1):

Opacity will the effect all styles of the element.
Try to Use

```
background: rgba(192,192,192, 0.2);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hello Anji, thanks a lot. I have tried with this code but the background is totally transparent and not sure why it changed the position of the text from right to left. Not sure why. :(

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h2 style="background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5); padding: 1em; max-width: 15em;  ;margin: 1em 10px; text-align: left;"><strong>HANDMADE TIES
</strong>DISCOVER NOW</h2>
&nbsp;
```

Comment: Hey Falguni thank you so much but it doesn't work, it changed the location from right to left and I can't see the box. it's totally transparent.

Comment: Now you can check my answer .You can see left align text and box with transparent gray color

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to make a background colour transparent and want the font content to remain untouched from background. The possible solution is you can add a transparent background in separate div and the content in separate div. Both div shall have different z-index.

So it's code is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#background{
position:fixed;
background:#c0c0c0;
opacity:0.2;
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
}


#content-wrapper{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
padding: 1em; 
max-width: 15em;
margin: 1em 10px; 
text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="background">
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">

<h2>HANDMADE TIES</h2>
<p>DISCOVER NOW</p>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Varun Setia thank you so much for your input, but I have tried this code and it made everything disappear.

Comment: That's so unfortunate, had you tried adjusting max-width with respect to content. Also would it be possible for you to share the screenshot? I can have a look at the issue.

Comment: thank you all. All sorted. cheers